# Can't create a view in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-xml

i've got a `ListView` with a custom adapter so i can customize the single row. I would create a view in the layout on the left that has as height all row height, and as width something like 5dp. So it will be like a little "strip" on the left of each row in the listview. I tried in this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@layout/cardwhite"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/viewlist"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="Partenza "
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <View 
        android:id="@id/viewlist"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:background="#52BD4F"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/viewlist"
        android:layout_below="@id/first"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

But using `android:layout_height="match_parent"` or `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` not works and the strip doesn't appear. If i write `android:layout_height="20dp"` it goes but of course it's not "dynamic". I don't understand why it desappears.. Any ideas?

Comment: post a picture currently have and expected to have

Comment: something like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SDiEs.png

Comment: nothing.. not appears

Comment: @User22791 There is only one difference between match_parent and fill_parent and that is fill_parent is deprecated starting from API Level 8 and is replaced by match_parent. Rest both are the same.

Comment: Yes, infact.. anyway still doesn't work. I can't understand why

Comment: you should use a horizontal linearlayout with your view on the left all the rest, where you could put your relativelayout with all your stuff in there. At that moment the match_parent should work. Note that fill_parent is replaced by match_parent since API8+

Comment: I have posted the answer below..I have tested that code and its working for your requirments..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify the layout accordingly. I have already done this one, so I'm just pasting it. You just need to make use of `android:layout_alignBottom` and `android:layout_alignTop` with proper `id` inside your `View`. Here is the screen shot !

[image: ScreenShot]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e5e4e2" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_normal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_type"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_dayName"
            android:background="#00ff00" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_dayName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Monday"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_dateNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="23"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_dayName"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Mark Attendance"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12sp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_monthName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_dateNumber"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Apr-14"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12sp" >
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--
          <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_line"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/text_line"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relative_row"/>
    -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: fill_parent is replaced by match_parent since API8+. You should correct your android:layout_height="fill_parent" to android:layout_height="match_parent" as you use match_parent everywhere else, for your code to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small trick. Instead of giving height to the view use a TextView and give Height as MatchParant and set TextSize according to your need and set Background color to your TextView. Hope this helps you!

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/col_status"
   android:layout_width="5dp"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
   android:background="#FFFFFF"
   android:rotation="180"
   android:textColor="@color/main_list_text"
   android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Comment: Well, Now appears.. but not for the entire height of the row..this situation is so strange..

Comment: Its because you might have also given Margins to it. so only it might not have taken the entire height of the row.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@layout/cardwhite"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/viewlist"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="Partenza "
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <View 
        android:id="@id/viewlist"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/first"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:background="#52BD4F"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/viewlist"
        android:layout_below="@id/first"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use relative layout just linearLayout

**sample:**

Beware that I dont have your `cardwhite` image so it wont be look like that one that you posted but just put the image in the linear layout background and it will look like the same as the one you posted.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@layout/cardwhite"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
        android:id="@id/viewlist"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#52BD4F" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="Customer 1"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/second"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="Meeting"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**result:**

[image]

Comment: It can also be done in RelativeLayout..i have posted the code above using relativeLayout..and getting the same answer like yours :)